# How to center child on parents horizontal axis in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple Chrome Extension that allows you to loop a section of a YouTube video. I'm able to put the button, I have all the logic behind it finished, styling etc except one thing. The buttons on the YouTube videos control panel, "Play" button, etc, are aligned in the middle of the control panels horizontal axis. However, my button sits at the bottom of it.

And the only way I'm able to make it have the same alignment as the other buttons is to set it's `bottom` to `13px`. Of course this is a static value and won't work on different screen resolutions and when the video goes fullscreen.

I just want to know a way to make it centered along the horizontal axis like the other buttons. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can u check with viewport value?

Comment: I think you may mean that they're centered vertically...

Comment: I assume you mean this? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: U can use percentages like `bottom:5%` instead of `bottom:13px`. Please paste the problematic code or a link to your site, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Ivan86 Thanks, that helped me solve it. I set `bottom` to `25%` and `position` to `absolute`. I noticed that I still had a problem with the button text being too small when I went fullscreen so I set `font-size` to `100%`. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ivan86 If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I posted. Glad you solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use percentages like `bottom:5%` instead of `bottom:13px` to position the bottom `relatively` to its `parent container`. The button will change it's distance from the bottom with resolution change but will keep the same ratio of `5%` relative to it's `container height` the whole time.

Comment: Had to tweak it slightly. Changed it from `position: absolute` to `position: relative` and changed `bottom: 25%` to `bottom: 45%`. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Peace